# tcl array to ruby hash parser

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, tcl

I have a file outputted from a TCL script, which has a TCL syntax'ed array, as below.

```
set data(item1) {
  xyz { 
     a { one two three 1 2 3}
     b { three one two 3 2 4}
   }
  lmn {
     z { "something" 1 2 3}
     d { "samething" 3 2 4}
   }
};

set data(item2) {
  xyz { 
     ss { 100 }
     sd { "sdss" 200 300}
   }
  lmn {
     ee { "xdf" 1 "2dsd" 3}
     pp { "dd" "fsdf" 3 2 4}
   }
};
```

Now I need to read this file in a Ruby program and build them into a Hash of Hashes, similar to something below, before I start consuming the required data:

```
data = {
  'item1' => {
     'xyz' => { 
        'a' => %w{one two three 1 2 3},
        'b' => %w{three one two 3 2 4}
     },

     'lmn' => {
        'z' => %w{something 1 2 3},
        'd' => %w{samething 3 2 4}
     }
   },

  'item2' => {
     'xyz' => { 
        'ss' => %w{100 },
        'sd' => %w{sdss 200 300}
     },
     'lmn' => {
        'ee' => %w{xdf 1 2dsd 3},
        'pp' => %w{dd fsdf 3 2 4}
     }
   }
}
```

Is there any Ruby utility or method that I can use for this purpose?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

No. You will have to build a parser. Take a look at [treetop](https://github.com/nathansobo/treetop).

It will help a lot to have some early basic knowledge of [compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) like compiling phases (lexical analyzer and syntax analyzer, you don't need semantic analyzer for this project).

Also, some basic understanding of [grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) will help, since is pre-requisite for compilers - but most likely you will stumble upon grammars while trying to figure out compilers.